# Adding a preferences fragment in my xamarin/visualstudio project

Tags: android, xamarin, android-preferences

Very new in android programming... I've created a simple priject just to learn.
Trying to add a preferences screen following [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) :
When I declare my Preferences class inside the namespace as follows:

```
 public class MySettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {

        @Override
        public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.preferences);
    }
```

I get errors such as "extends" cannot be found and many other saying it is not the right context where to write it
what I am missing?

Comment: Why are you trying to mix  Java code with C#??

Comment: @cricket_007 if you have time, fleshing that out would be an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753298/how-to-develop-applications-preference-settings-screen-in-xamarin-crossplatform

Comment: thanks for clarifiyng I knew it was something stupid but was unable to find out by myself!!

Comment: cricket_007 thank you very much for the link! really very useful for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are mixing Java and C# syntax, in C# you use a colon instead of the word 'extends' to inherit a class, and the 'override' modifier is used instead of '@Override'

Your code would end up looking like this

```
 public class MySettingsFragment : PreferenceFragment
 {


    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java and C# are similar and sometime is a pro.. but not this time! Thank you very much!